# Material UI Autocomplete displays "No Options" when using async data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

i want to hit an API to fill the `options` of my Autocomplete. i do this using `useEffect`, and can see that an array of data is in the response, but will not show up in the Autocomplete.

[image]

if i hardcode the parsed response into a JS array and stick it into the initialState object, it works. does the Autocomplete not detect state changes or something? i am following [this example](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#asynchronous-requests).

[image]

there are no errors. a console log statement shows the parsed body of the response is a usable array. so i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

the response looks like this before being parsed:

```
body: "[{"addressList":[{"address":"78 Pine Ave S","city":"Bend","province":"Oregon","postalCode":"89879","country":"USA"},{"address":"998 76 St S","city":"Bend","province":"Oregon","postalCode":"86585","country":"USA"}],"emailList":["adawg@gmail.com","aliyahsamson@yahoo.ca"],"_id":"5f579f50f02ea700316058d7","firstName":"Billy Bob","lastName":"Johnson","alias":"BB-Dawg","__v":0},{"addressList":[],"emailList":[],...
```

the state i am using as well as the effects:

```
const initialState = {
  contacts: [],
};

useEffect(() => {
    let active = true;
    setState({ ...state, loading: true });
    const url = `${environment.api.contacts}/listAll`;

    (async () => {
      await axios.get(url)
        .then((response) => {
          const contacts = JSON.parse(response.data.body);
          console.log('got contacts:', contacts);
          setState({ ...state, contacts });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error getting contacts:', error);
        })
        .then(() => setState({ ...state, loading: false }));
    })();

    return () => { active = false };
  }, []);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!state.open) setState({ ...state, contacts: [] });
  }, [state.open]);
```

here is the Autocomplete

```
<Autocomplete
              options={state.contacts}
              getOptionLabel={(contact: Contact) => getFullName(contact)}
              onChange={(event: any, contact: any) => { if (contact) handleContactChange(contact) }}
              renderInput={(params) => 
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  label="Search for a Contact..."
                  variant="outlined"
                  InputProps={{
                    ...params.InputProps,
                    style: {
                      height: 44,
                      padding: '0 14px',
                    },
                    endAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="end">
                        <Search />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                  }}
                  InputLabelProps={{
                    ...params.InputLabelProps,
                    style: {
                      height: 44,
                      ...({ top: '-6px' }),
                    },
                  }}
                />
              }
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a state called 'isLoading' to keep check on async call response. Initially it is set to false and once I get back the response, I set it to true. You can add few params to Autocomplete box as follows.

```
       <Autocomplete
          loading={isLoading}
          loadingText="Loading..."
          noOptionsText="No Options found"      
          options={state.contacts}
          getOptionLabel={(contact: Contact) => getFullName(contact)}
          onChange={(event: any, contact: any) => { if (contact) handleContactChange(contact) }}
          renderInput={(params) => 
            <TextField
              {...params}
              label="Search for a Contact..."
              variant="outlined"
              InputProps={{
                ...params.InputProps,
                style: {
                  height: 44,
                  padding: '0 14px',
                },
                endAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="end">
                    <Search />
                  </InputAdornment>
                ),
              }}
              InputLabelProps={{
                ...params.InputLabelProps,
                style: {
                  height: 44,
                  ...({ top: '-6px' }),
                },
              }}
            />
          }
        />
```

Once you get the response from your API call, set isLoading to false.